# Tone Marks in Thai localization rendered as separate characters in C++/DirectX render

Tags: c++, localization, directx, directx-11

So this is the string I'm trying to display

[image]

And this is what gets rendered

[image]

The string "ตั้งค่า" is being stored as a wstring, and rendered using wchar, so UTF-16.  I've tried Teko Regular (Google font) and Arial (Windows font), so both support Thai, but I don't understand enough about Thai characters or Unicode to understand what needs to happen to combine those tone marks into a single character during my render.

Comment: How are you rendering the characters? I guess whatever code you are using doesn't support/account for composed characters

Comment: I inherited this code, and I'm still working through it, myself, but it appears we are saving the font as a D3D11Texture2D, and saving the pixel size and position of individual characters on that texture, then rendering that texture onto a Quad and using the saved size/position to display the correct character

Comment: The naive approach is great for simple cases but for more complex languages you need a proper text rendering library to render the whole string in one go not individual characters